# How to establish a UDP connection over the internet using the NetworkComms.Net library in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, networkcomms.net

I am trying to establish two connections (TCP and UDP) from a Client to a Server via the internet. The TCP connection is working fine but the UDP connection getting closed immediately and so it can't be established properly.

All is working fine if I am testing it locally on the same machine. Both connections including the data transfer are working as expected.

I have opened the Port for both (TCP and UDP) on the server.

Server:

```
Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ip, port));
Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.UDP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ip, port));
```

Client:

```
ConnectionInfo connInfoTCP = new ConnectionInfo(ip, port);
ConnectionInfo connInfoUDP = new ConnectionInfo(ip, port);

try
{                
userConnection = TCPConnection.GetConnection(connInfoTCP);
userConnectionUDP = UDPConnection.GetConnection(connInfoUDP, 
UDPOptions.Handshake);
}
...
```

The TCP connection is getting established quite fine but the UDP connection is getting closed immediately.

What I am wondering: if I try it locally I am getting the same networkcomms network identifier for both connections, while I am trying it on the server the UDP networkcomms network identifier always shows AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. But port and remote ip are fine.

This is my log output on the server:

```
29.05.2019 14:54:16: Client connected :c7WvezQPAEqh8bIHwljipA Protocol: TCP Remote ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:55653
29.05.2019 14:54:17: Client connected :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Protocol: UDP Remote ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53951
29.05.2019 14:54:17: Client disconnected:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

This are the values for the log output above:

```
Client connected: ConnectionInfo.NetworkIdentifier
Protocol: connection.ConnectionInfo.ConnectionType
Remote ip: connection.ConnectionInfo.RemoteEndPoint
```

A general question: Is this the best way to implement such a connection or would there be a better way of doing it? Or perhaps a better solution than the NetworkComms.Net library?

Comment: Are you able to replicate this behaviour if you modify line 172 (on a test client) of https://github.com/MarcFletcher/NetworkComms.Net/blob/master/ExamplesConsole/AdvancedSend.cs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tested it with the example file and I have the same thing. It returns me AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA for the identifier.

Comment: Back to your example. After the UDP connection appears to have been 'disconnected' have you tried enumerating NetworkComms.GetExistingConnection(... providing the remote ip, port, UDP for connection type? It may just be that the logging is being misinterpreted and the handshake has been completed successfully. i.e. the client with the unknown identifier get's disconnected but ultimately replaced with the known identifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I have changed it to monitor the Existing Connections with all the details. Unfortunately, it is like in the log. The Connection is gone.
If I disable the Handshake it will stay connected and I can transmit data. The problem is that I now can not identify a specific client? They all get the AAA.. Identifier. That's why I choose the Handshake ;)